# Label above a body in Phaser

Tags: javascript, game-engine, game-physics, phaser-framework

I have an array with bodies. For each one of them I want to put a label with some info. I've managed to do it, but when I turn them the label turns too.

```
// Main body
players[id] = game.add.sprite(game.world.randomX, 200, sprite, sprite_ini);
game.physics.p2.enable(players[id]);

players[id].animations.add('walk', [1,2,3,4], 10, true);
players[id].animations.add('stand', [0], 0, true);
players[id].animations.add('jump', [5], 0, true);

// Add weapon
bazuca = game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'bazuca');
players[id].addChild(bazuca);

// Labels   
players[id].body.label_nome = game.add.text(
        -35, 
        -55, 
        "Info", 
        { font: "bold 14px Arial", fill: color});
players[id].addChild(players[id].body.label_nome);
```

And they are turned with

```
players[id].scale.x = -1;
```

The animation turns and works perfectly, the weapon also turns and stays in place, but the label also turns. How can I avoid that? The label should move with the body, but not turn.

Comment: Groups are designed to be scaled, rotated and moved as if you were dealing with a single sprite. I'd try three things: first option - rotate the group as you are doing now, then rotate the text only once again; second option - rotate every children (but the text) by itself; third - have the text outside of the group and update its position manually.

Comment: I liked the third one best, should I update the position in update function or with some callback? callback seems better, but is there a body position change callback?hehe

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions:

- Kamen Minkov's one, i.e. keeping the labels out of the groups and update their position on each frame ([there doesn't seem to be](http://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.Physics.P2.Body.html#members) an "onMove" signal or something).
- Since you're using P2, you could actually physics-enable the labels, set "body.fixedRotation = true" on them, and create a constraint between each label and each sprite to make thhe labels follow the sprites.

The second solution seems more elegant and maintainable but performance-wise the first one is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the label to be the same x value as the item it is labeling, and the y value of the label to be less than that of the object. Here is example code:

```
//in create():
label.anchor.setTo(.5, .5); /*sets positioning to center. 
You need to make sure that arcade physics are applied to label*/

//in update():
label.x = object.x;
label.y = object.y - 60; 
//change the 60 to whatever looks good to you when running.
```

To apply arcade physics:

```
//in create():
game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE); // do this once 
game.physics.enable(label/*change this to what you want the physics to apply to*/, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
```

Hope this helps.